# Step by step form using jQuery hiding wrong divs on clicking back on first step

Tags: jquery

I've created a step by step form that uses jQuery to step through 3 steps.

On the first step, how can I adjust the jQuery to hide my `customise` div and show the `entire_product` div when I click back?

At the moment when I click back on the first step it's hides all the divs.

---

I'm using jQuery to initially show the `entire_product` div then when the link is clicked, it hides the `entire_product` div and shows the `customise` div instead (code is below).

```
<div class="entire_product">
    Content here.
    <a id="customise" class="configure-demo" href="#">Configure new system &amp; get quote</a>
</div>
```

This is the `customise` div:

```
<div class="customise" style="display:none;">
    <form id="customisesystem" method="post" action="">
        <div id="first-step">
            <div class="steps">
                <p><b>Step 1 of 3</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-buttons"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="customise-area">
                <p>Options 1</p>

                <div id="customise-area">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hardware[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="second-step">
            <div class="steps">
                <p><b>Step 2 of 3</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-buttons"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="customise-area">
                <p>Options 2</p>

                <div id="customise-area">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="software[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div id="third-step">
            <div class="steps">
                <p><b>Step 3 of 3</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-buttons"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="customise-area">
                <p>Options 3</p>

                <div id="customise-area">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </form>
</div>
```

I then have a load of jQuery, that is creating back and next buttons to step through the 3 steps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var prevLink = '<a class="back" href="#">Back</a>';
var nextLink = '</a><a class="next" href="#">Next</a>';
var navHTML = '<div class="prev-next">' +
                         prevLink +
                         nextLink +
                      '</div>';
var prevLink = '<a class="back" href="#">Back</a>';
var nextLink = '</a><a class="next" href="#">Next</a>';
var navHTML = '<div class="prev-next">' +
                         prevLink +
                         nextLink +
                      '</div>';
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            // init
            $('#customisesystem > div')
                .hide()
                .prepend(navHTML);
            $('#first-step .prev').remove();
            $('#last-step .next').remove();

            // show first step
            $('#first-step').show();

            $('a.next').click(function(){
                var whichStep = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

                if( whichStep == 'first-step' )
                {
                    // validate first-step
                }
                else if( whichStep == 'second-step' )
                {
                    // validate second-step
                }
                else if( whichStep == 'last-step' )
                {
                    // validate last-step
                }

                $(this).parent().parent().hide().next().show();
            });

            $('a.back').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().hide().prev().show();
            });
        });


jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$("#customise").click(function(){
    $(".entire_product").hide();
    $(".customise").show();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: 1) You should clean up your jQuery code.
2) I see you calling the PHP function `the_title()` many times. depending what's on the back end of that, you may want to set `$the_title` from the function and echo that for each instance.

Comment: @Mooseman 1) As in formatting? 2) It's from Wordpress but that doesn't really effect the whole step process at the moment.

Comment: 1) Just things like removing comments for production, etc. 2) It's unrelated to your problem, but keep things running faster on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/nnKp4/1/

```
 $('a.back').click(function(){
          var whichStep = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
          if(whichStep == "first-step"){
            $(".customise").hide();
            $(".entire_product").show();
          }
          else{
            $(this).parent().parent().hide().prev().show();
          }
 });
```

Comment: Welcome.. Happy to be Helpful... :)